# How to use $ as a currency symbol in a list environment?

Tags: symbols, lists, markdown

This is not exactly a problem while using ShareLaTeX. However, I am trying to create a list in a Markdown cell in a Jupyter Notebook. So far I had no problem creating a list using LaTeX code.

However, when I try to do the following, I don't get the desired output.

```
\begin{enumerate}
    \item This is $\$30,000$
    \item This is $\$30,000$
\end{enumerate}
```

This is the standard syntax which gives me the desired output in ShareLaTeX.

**Alternate Approach:**

I have tried creating the list in the HTML environment as follows

```
<ul>
    <li> This is $\$30,000$
    <li> This is $\$500,000$          
</ul>
```

and this works.

My question is how can I make it work under the LaTeX environment.

**Update**

**Approach 1**
[image]

**Approach 2**
[image]

**Approach 3**
[image]

**Approach 4**
[image]

I need to fix the **Approach 4**.

Comment: This off topic I think, but anyways: the LaTeX in a notebook isn't LaTeX, it's MathJax, a JavaScript library for rendering *math* which supports a subset of LaTeX syntax. There isn't support for arbitrary code from LaTeX. Use Markdown to make the list and escape the dollar signs with a backslash, i.e. `1. This is \$30,000 2. This is \$30,000` with a newline before `2.`.

Comment: Note that `$\$30,000$` will give incorrect output with TeX, because there will be a thin space after the comma that's not wanted. I know that it's common in the US to separate thousands with a comma, but then you should type `$30{,}000$` to avoid the thin space; better with just a thin space and no comma, however `$30\,000$`. The dollar symbol can be inside or outside the math formula.

Comment: I am having no problem running this code in `sharelatex`. I have tried using `$\$30$`, but still don't get the result in `Jupyter Notebook`.

Comment: What code gives what result? This is what it looks like for me: https://i.stack.imgur.com/aD6mK.png

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Please check the update.

Comment: Why can't you use Markdown for the lists? `\begin{itemize}` etc. doesn't work at all for me, have you got any addons or similar?

Comment: @TorbjørnT. It's complicated. I need to follow the `latex` style as much as I can.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. I have been using `\begin{itemize}` all the time until I came across such a situation to have `$` symbol in a list and now I am in trouble.

Comment: (I don't understand your reasons, but fair enough.) I'm guessing, after some searching, that you're using the `latex_envs` extension? That is important information, because that extension is what actually renders your code to HTML. And I also think that this makes the question definitely off topic, and that you should either post it on [so] yourself, or flag it and ask for migration. (The first option is quicker.)  It's possible that it's a bug in the extension, in which case log an issue at https://github.com/jfbercher/jupyter_latex_envs (if that is the origin of the extension of course)

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Yes, you are right. I have posted the question on Stack Overflow.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it seems to be about the use of the `latex_envs` extension in Jupyter Notebook, which is not within the scope of this site. Author has re-posted on StackOverflow where the question fits better.